# MongoDB Aggregation Lookup Match Array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections, a collection with users and a collection with groups. In `groups` the documents look like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("...")
    "members": [ObjectId("..."), ObjectId("..."), ObjectId("...")]
}
```

In the `users` collection the documents look like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("...")
    "first_name": "...",
    "last_name": "...",
    "phone": "..."
}
```

What I want to do is an aggregation in the `users` collection where I add a `$lookup` stage to the pipeline where I go inside the `groups` collection and get the group from the user based on whether the `_id` from the user document is inside the `members` array in the  group document.

I have the following but I don't know how I'd proceed.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("...") }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "groups",
            "let": {"_id": "$_id"},
            "pipeline": [{"$match": ???}], <- match when $$_id is inside $members
            "as": "group"
    }
]);
```

I know that the aggregation framework in MongoDB doesn't work with arrays and that there is an `$unwind` stage but I don't really know how I would combine `$unwind` and `$match` to get the result I want.

What I want:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    "group": ObjectId("..."),
    (other fields here)
}
```

I use MongoDB server version 3.7.2

Comment: What's your MongoDB server version?

Comment: It's MongoDB 3.7.2 @chridam

Comment: Did you mean 3.6.2? If so, no need to do the extra filtering since the `$lookup` aggregation pipeline stage NOW works directly with an array (on 3.3.4 version).

Comment: What do you mean by "no need to do the extra filtering" @chridam?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try below aggregation one of two ways using `$lookup` and `$lookup` pipeline.

$lookup

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"_id":ObjectId(..)}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"groups",
    "localField":"_id",
    "foreignField":"members",
    "as":"group"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$group"},
  {"$unwind":"$group.members"},
  {"$match":{"group.members":ObjectId(..)}}
])
```

$lookup pipeline

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"_id":ObjectId(..)}},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"groups",
    "let":{"_id":"$_id"},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{"$expr":{"$in":["$$_id","$members"]}}},
      {"$unwind":"$members"},
      {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$$_id","$members"]}}}
    ],
    "as":"members"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! After a bit of fiddling around I made it work for my use-case. The first `$match` already gave back the right document so I removed the `$unwind` and `$match` and added an `$unwind` and an `$addFields` after the `$lookup` stage to extract the `_id` field from the group and set it as a field in the user document.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. The first one working fine but second one($lookup pipeline) not working for me, is there any other reason please?

Comment: You sexy stallion thank you